# Waiting for the exact text that takes at least 2 lines on the UI to be present

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, fluentwait

The following method works if that text takes only one line:

```
public void screen_heading_should_be(String scrheading) {
        Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(ldriver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(AppiumBy.id("screen_heading"), scrheading));
    }
```

How do you wait for the exact text that takes two (or more) lines on the UI?

The text I'm waiting for:
"*Please set your course 
 preferences to proceed.*"

`scrheading` is the one-line string ("*Please set your course preferences to proceed.*") that's present in my Step Definitions' Gherkin step (Cucumber), so, it has to be a user-friendly one-line string. Plus, texts in my app can even be on three and more lines, depending on the phone device's screen size/resolution (mobile UI automation).

I was thinking about applying this: `screen_heading.getText().replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ")`, but it's a string which is not accepted by the 'ExpectedConditions' from above. 'By' is required instead.

Comment: Edit your question and post the exact two-line string that you are waiting for. Is there some reason you don't just create the exact two-line string in `scrheading`?

Comment: Edited the question. Hope it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: `scrheading = "Please set your course\r\npreferences to proceed."`

Comment: Good solution, but not for my case. I need one step that would work for many instances of `scrheading`(with various string values) in the app. Plus, again, the line breaks could appear anywhere within the text, depending on the device.